# Convert sub-query into CTE

Tags: sql-server

How can I change this sub-query into CTE so I can include it later into a view

```
(SELECT
     x.Lack_ID_Ver_a            
    ,x.Lack_ID_Ver_b                
    ,x.Lack_ID_Ver_c
    ,x.[Name]
    ,x.[Filing_key]
    ,x.[filingId]
    ,(CAST((COALESCE(Lack_ID_Ver_a ,0)) + (COALESCE(Lack_ID_Ver_b ,0)) + (COALESCE(Lack_ID_Ver_c ,0))AS DECIMAL(10,2))/3) AS Q5_8_Lack_Identity_Ver
    
    FROM (
    SELECT 
    [Name] 
    ,[Filing_key]
    ,[filingId]
    ,CASE WHEN [NewCustomer]    = '173220000' THEN '1' ELSE '0' END AS Lack_ID_Ver_a           
    ,CASE WHEN [OccasionTran]  = '173220000' THEN '1' ELSE '0' END AS Lack_ID_Ver_b                 
    ,CASE WHEN [MaterialChange] = '173220000' THEN '1' ELSE '0' END AS Lack_ID_Ver_c     
    FROM  [stage_DEV].[dbo].[table]  WHERE filingtype='current'
    ) x )
```

So I would start with

```
;WITH LackID AS
```

but I don't quite understand how to rearrange this query, given that I need to have the

```
(CAST((COALESCE(Lack_ID_Ver_a ,0)) + (COALESCE(Lack_ID_Ver_b ,0)) + (COALESCE(Lack_ID_Ver_c ,0))AS DECIMAL(10,2))/3) AS Q5_8_Lack_Identity_Ver
```

incorporated

Comment: FYI `;` is a statement terminator, not a `WITH` prefix. Terminate all your statements correctly with a `;` rather than adding one to a CTE.

Comment: Why do you have your whole query in parenthesis `( ) `? Is this part of a bigger query, because that would influence how this has to be done.

Comment: Question is unclear because `SELECT * FROM mytable` can be re-written as `WITH abc AS (SELECT * FROM mytable)  SELECT * FROM abc;`, and it is unclear why that should not be the case in this situation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are just trying to convert what you are showing into a CTE then this is how you would do it:

```
WITH LackID AS (
    SELECT 
        [Name] 
        , [Filing_key]
        , [filingId]
        , CASE WHEN [NewCustomer]    = '173220000' THEN '1' ELSE '0' END AS Lack_ID_Ver_a           
        , CASE WHEN [OccasionTran]  = '173220000' THEN '1' ELSE '0' END AS Lack_ID_Ver_b                 
        , CASE WHEN [MaterialChange] = '173220000' THEN '1' ELSE '0' END AS Lack_ID_Ver_c     
    FROM [stage_DEV].[dbo].[table]
    WHERE filingtype='current'
)
SELECT
    Lack_ID_Ver_a            
    , Lack_ID_Ver_b                
    , Lack_ID_Ver_c
    , [Name]
    , [Filing_key]
    , [filingId]
    , (CAST((COALESCE(Lack_ID_Ver_a ,0)) + (COALESCE(Lack_ID_Ver_b ,0)) + (COALESCE(Lack_ID_Ver_c ,0))AS DECIMAL(10,2))/3) AS Q5_8_Lack_Identity_Ver
FROM LackID;
```

But if this is part of a larger query, we need to see it in context.

As per your comment, if you need the calculated value as well, you would do the following which allows you to then join on other tables:

```
WITH LackID AS (
    SELECT
        x.Lack_ID_Ver_a            
        , x.Lack_ID_Ver_b                
        , x.Lack_ID_Ver_c
        , x.[Name]
        , x.[Filing_key]
        , x.[filingId]
        , (CAST((COALESCE(Lack_ID_Ver_a ,0)) + (COALESCE(Lack_ID_Ver_b ,0)) + (COALESCE(Lack_ID_Ver_c ,0))AS DECIMAL(10,2))/3) AS Q5_8_Lack_Identity_Ver
    FROM (
      SELECT 
          [Name] 
          , [Filing_key]
          , [filingId]
          , CASE WHEN [NewCustomer]    = '173220000' THEN '1' ELSE '0' END AS Lack_ID_Ver_a           
          , CASE WHEN [OccasionTran]  = '173220000' THEN '1' ELSE '0' END AS Lack_ID_Ver_b                 
          , CASE WHEN [MaterialChange] = '173220000' THEN '1' ELSE '0' END AS Lack_ID_Ver_c     
      FROM [stage_DEV].[dbo].[table]
      WHERE filingtype='current'
    ) x
)
SELECT
    Lack_ID_Ver_a            
    , Lack_ID_Ver_b                
    , Lack_ID_Ver_c
    , [Name]
    , [Filing_key]
    , [filingId]
    , Q5_8_Lack_Identity_Ver
FROM LackID;
```

Comment: Thank you. The idea is to use an Inner Join to connect this part (or the results of this) with a larger Select query and then create a view. My understanding is that LackID can essentially be used similar to a temp table.  Is here a way to test this like: Select Q5_8_Lack_Identity_Ver from LackID (does not work- hence I am asking).